# 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have WEbAPI2 back end.

I try to send form data from postman

[image]

But get this error

> "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'StartWorkingDay' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",

Here is code of my controller

```
// POST: api/StartWorkingDays
[ResponseType(typeof(StartWorkingDay))]
public IHttpActionResult PostStartWorkingDay(StartWorkingDay startWorkingDay)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.StartWorkingDays.Add(startWorkingDay);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);
}
```

When I send it via raw data, all okay

[image]

How I can make it receive `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Seems that you're doing POST to incorrect action method URL. Check your `$.ajax` or `$http` request, perhaps you just need a GET method or you need to set `Content-Type: application/json` header for AJAX request.

Comment: I don't do AJAX request, I do request from app@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Have you using `HttpPostedFileBase` placeholder for Web API controllers instead of MVC controllers? You need to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` for Web API, or place this in WebApiConfig.cs: `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1)

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

> Form data is encoded as name/value pairs, similar to a URI query string. This is the default format for POST.

`multipart/form-data`

> Form data is encoded as a multipart MIME message. Use this format if you are uploading a file to the server.

Use enctype x-www-form-urlencoded, not form-data in postman

Answer (score 1):

Select form-data in postman. Add key "startWorkingDay", and deserialize the request parameter in your requisite function. And, you are done.

[image: Postman Snap]

**Code:**

```
    // POST: api/StartWorkingDays
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(StartWorkingDay))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostStartWorkingDay()
        {
            var startWorkingDay = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StartWorkingDay>(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["startWorkingDay"]);
            //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest(ModelState);
            //}

            db.StartWorkingDays.Add(startWorkingDay);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);
        }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF5YH.png
```